# Socket - Read as much as possible with timeout

Tags: c++, sockets, io, boost-asio

I've had a look at the async timeout example found in the [asio documentation](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_4_8/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp), but I was wondering if it is possible to place an asynch read (for upto N bytes) with a timeout of S seconds, but where if a timeout occurs it will return a buffer of bytes read upuntil the timeout has occured instead of an error code.

For example if I were to perform a read (recv) for 1000 bytes with a timeout of 10seconds and only 300 bytes arrive before the 10 seconds rolls around, I'd like those 300 bytes to be returned - is this possible using asio? or even the berkeley sockets interface?

Comment: This is almost never a sensible thing to do. What's your outer problem? There's almost certainly a better solution to it.

Comment: For berkeley sockets you get timeout if there is no data in the buffer, so you keep reading until received N bytes or desired time elapsed. After every partial read you have to update both timeout value and number of requesting bytes. Not giving an example, as not sure if you're interested in non-asio solution using blocking sockets.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do it:

1. Set up an `asio` request to read *up to* however many bytes you haven't yet read.
2. Set up an `asio` timer to fire in however much time it will be until the time runs out.
3. If you get a read hit that fills the number of bytes you wanted, cancel the timer.
4. If you get a partial read, set up another partial read and another timer.

But this is almost never a sensible thing to do. Whatever your outer problem is that you think this solves, there's almost certainly a better solution.

Comment: Please explain the downvote. If I'm incorrect, I'd like to correct myself. If you're incorrect, I'd like to correct you. If there's a better way, I'd like to know it. If I was unclear, I'd like to clarify.